# There is a way to pass the option " pci=[’00:...,rdm_policy=relaxed’] " to libvirt?

Tags: xen, libvirt

I can run (successfully) a xen virtual machine use the classical method with xl

```
xl create -f myvm.xenxl.cfg
```

I know also how to convert from xl format to libvirt xml

```
virsh -c xen:///system domxml-from-native xen-xl myvm.xenxl.cfg > myvm.xml
```

What is the problem? I had to pass a pci device to xen machine, but this work ONLY with this option

```
pci = [ "0000:08:04.0,rdm_policy=relaxed" ]
```

when I convert to xml it generate this for the pci device

```
  <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='no'>
      <driver name='xen'/>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
    </hostdev>
```

as you can se the "rdm_policy=relaxed" is ignored so if I start with libvirt generate this error

```
(XEN) [VT-D] It's disallowed to assign 0000:08:04.0 with shared RMRR at f1ffd000 for Dom3.
(XEN) d3: assign (0000:08:04.0) failed (-1)
```

my question is: no way to pass the rdm_policy to libvirt?

Comment: im not sure what kind of devices you are trying, but https://bugs.xenserver.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/XSO-720 seems that its not supposed to be supported?

Comment: the device is supported, and I can run the domU sucessfully, but only usning xl create(because accept the rdm_policy). I want to run it with libvirt